# can anyone tell me what -a in a unix shell test condition means?

Tags: unix, shell

Can anyone tell me what `-a` means in unix.  Please see the following code:

```
if [ "$x"  = "$x" -a "y" -eq 0 ]  ; then
echo $x
else 
echo $y
```

Comment: Please improve your wording, i.e. *anyone* instead of *any1* and *please* instead of *plz*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it means "and". -o is "or".

From `man bash`

```
expr1 -a expr2
                     True if both expr1 and expr2 are true.
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting **[4.1 Bourne Shell Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)** *(i.e. the manual, online, with anchors)* :

> `test`
> `[` 
>     Evaluate a conditional
>   expression expr. Each operator and
>   operand must be a separate argument.
>   
>     Expressions are composed of the
>   primaries described below in Bash
>   Conditional Expressions.  
>     `test`
>   does not accept any options, nor does
>   it accept and ignore an argument of --
>   as signifying the end of options. 
>   
> ...
>   
>  `expr1 -a expr2` 
>   
>     **True if both expr1 and expr2 are true.**